How to construct the monotone union of disks
In proof of the Brown-Stallings theorem, Milnor mentioned that $M$ is a monotone union of disks. But the author didn't mention how to construct such monotone disks $W_1 \subset W_2 \subset \cdots \subset M$. Could anyone show the details of the construction?
J. Milnor, "Differential Topology", in Lectures in Modern Mathematics, volume 2nd, 1964.

You have to add many more detail for the question to be answerable.

@MoisheKohan, may I ask you where my answer is wrong? Where am I wrong in my belief that the W_i sequence I construct is monotone just because my $W_{i+1}$ contains $W_i$ by construction, i.e. $W_1 \subset W_2 \subset \ldots$? And by the assumption in the lemma (that every compact is embedded in an open ball) I can just take a ball around the compact $\overline{W_{i}\cup B_{i+1}}$?

@AI.G Thanks. How can we show that $B_{i+1} \subset M$?

I'm not sure if you can see my deleted answer, but I take all the $B_i$ from a topological base of balls covering $M$, so each $B_i$ is an open ball in $M$. But I'm still hoping for a feedback on why my answer was voted for deletion by 5 users in the low-quality queue.

@AI.G I can't see your deleted answer. Could you type the answer again?

Here follows the contents of my answer copied verbatim; if you find it helpful and correct and no one argues against, I'll vote for undeletion. Here it goes: If you'd allow me to use that any connected paracompact locally Euclidean space is second-countable (https://mathoverflow.net/a/237), then I'd (try to) construct the $W_i$s on top of a countable base of balls $B_1,B_2,\ldots$ as follows:

Take $W_1=B_1$.
For $W_{i+1}$ take (by lemma assumption) a ball around the closure of $W_i \cup B_{i+1}$ (which is a compact because $W_i$ and $B_{i+1}$ are balls).

